# Web Api and where should I contorol Request Header data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In Asp.net Web Api, I want to control, request  "access token" key is (which is in request header) valid or not. But I cound't decide where should I implement this kind of control. ActionFilter or controller constructor etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a [DelegatingHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)? It is part if the Web Api pipeline and executes before Routing and Controller handlers.

A really simple handler for access tokens may look like this. You would implement IsValid as you see fit.

```
public class ValidateTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var token = request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (token == null or !IsValid(token))
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for code and link. I implement your solution to my Api and it worked well. Know I am able to check my access token